# How to make Sublime Text 3 more look like VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, sublimetext3

I went through many themes of **Sublime Text 3**, but I found that there are limitless themes for it. I love the **Visual Studio Code** UI, but I can't afford the harm which my PC will have to stand. It uses much System Memory, but I am a huge fan of VSCode.
I came to know that Visual Studio Code runs on the **configuredByTheme**. But I did not find any Sublime alternative. If anybody has the answer to this question, then all the VSCode Lovers, who cannot stand the increased memory usage of VSCode, will be very much thankful to the Answerer.

How to make Sublime Text 3 more look like VSCode? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if sublime supports themes you can write a theme that mimics your VSC theme? How much memory does your VSC use. It does not hurt my PC.

Comment: It doesn't hurt the PC, but it affects the performance of other apps. NetBeans, Google Chrome, Microsoft Office, and even VSCode slows down when VSCode is in use. EVEN ON A SSD.

Comment: Sorry! Just wanted an alternative. Writing full theme is a time-waste job. If there is already available, so why I would waste that time? But I think sublime should improve its UI. VSCode just looks cool. Please tell if there is already available.

Comment: @rioV8, How much RAM your PC has?